# Passing an object to a controller with Ajax - which contains an Enum

Tags: ajax, enums, spring-data, thymeleaf

I'm trying to pass an object Consumer to my Controller. A Consumer has a one-to-many relationship with Policy. This is what I tried:

```
function changeConsumer(){

  var newConsumer = {
            "id" : /*[[${consumer.id}]]*/,
            "name" : document.getElementById('0').value,
            "endpoint" : document.getElementById('1').value,
            "policies" : /*[[${policies}]]*/
    }

    $.ajax({
     type: "PUT",
     url: "/rest/consumer/update",
     data: JSON.stringify(newConsumer),
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     success : function(response) {
       ...
     });
   }
```

If I pass the Consumer like this, with an empty array of Policies - it works:

```
function changeConsumer(){

      var newConsumer = {
                "id" : /*[[${consumer.id}]]*/,
                "name" : document.getElementById('0').value,
                "endpoint" : document.getElementById('1').value,
                "policies" : []
        }

        $.ajax({
         type: "PUT",
         url: "/rest/consumer/update",
         data: JSON.stringify(newConsumer),
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success : function(response) {
           ...
         });
       }
```

This is the stacktrace I'm receiving, which leads me to think there a problem with the Enum "Effect" in the Policy object:

```
2017-11-18 16:28:22.255  WARN 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of com.policyMgmt.policy.Effect out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@56bd85f4; line: 1, column: 93] (through reference chain: com.policyMgmt.consumer.Consumer["policies"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.policyMgmt.policy.Policy["effect"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.policyMgmt.policy.Effect out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@56bd85f4; line: 1, column: 93] (through reference chain: com.policyMgmt.consumer.Consumer["policies"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.policyMgmt.policy.Policy["effect"])
2017-11-18 16:28:22.255  WARN 7884 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of com.policyMgmt.policy.Effect out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@56bd85f4; line: 1, column: 93] (through reference chain: com.policyMgmt.consumer.Consumer["policies"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.policyMgmt.policy.Policy["effect"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.policyMgmt.policy.Effekt out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@56bd85f4; line: 1, column: 93] (through reference chain: com.policyMgmt.consumer.Consumer["policies"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.policyMgmt.policy.Policy["effect"])
```

The Policy object which looks like this:

```
    @Entity
    public class Policy {
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue
            @Column(name = "id")
            private Integer id;

            @Column(name = "name")
            private String name;

            @Column (name = "consumer_id")
            private Integer consumer;

            @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
            @Column(name="effect")
            private Effect effect;

            public Policy() {}
    ....
}
```

Maybe it helps, this is what a Consumer looks like:

```
@Entity
public class Consumer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "endpoint")
    private String endpoint;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name ="consumer_id")
    private List<Policy> policies;


    public Consumer() {
    }
}
```

Rest API

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/consumer")
public class ConsumerController {
    ...
    @PutMapping(value = "/update")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Consumer> updateConsumer(@RequestBody Consumer consumer) {}
...
}
```

Does anyone have experience passing enums within Ajax to a Controller?

Comment: What is `${policies}` -- what's the data type & contents?

Comment: Like the Policy-object I have copied. Array of policies which look like this: policies  [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "policy x",
        "consumer": 5,
        "effekt": "deny"
    },{
        "id":2,
        "name": "policy y",
        "consumer": 2,
        "effekt": "allow"}]

Comment: Can you do a "view source" and tell me what this part looks like in the browser, after server-side rendering?  -- `"policies" : /*[[${policies}]]*/`

Comment: [{"consumer":5,"effekt":{"$type":"Effekt","$name":"deny"},"id":15,"name":"PolicyTest1"},{"consumer":5,"effekt":{"$type":"Effekt","$name":"deny"},"id":16,"name":"PolicyTest2"},...]

Comment: When I copy & paste your last comment, I am getting some very funny hidden characters along with the visible ones -- a number of \u200c (ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER) and \u200b (ZERO WIDTH SPACE), always together in a pair.  Try pasting your JSON here (and click "Validate JSON"):  https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Sorry, for presentation reason I made the objects simple. This is the real JSON. If I validate that JSON, its ok. But like in the warning, it has someting to do with that ENUM [{
 "consumer": 5,
 "effekt": {
  "$type": "Effekt",
  "$name": "deny"
 },
 "expiration": "2018-06-06T02:00:00.000+02:00",
 "id": 15,
 "intent": null,
 "name": "PolicyTest",
 "resource": null
}]

Comment: Can you add the source for the `Effect` enum?

Comment: Very simply, nothing special: public enum Effekt {
 allow,
 deny
} Thats all

Comment: I'm confused about why you're using the spelling "effect" in the question but "effekt" in the comments.

Comment: Also -- is there a `@Controller` involved in this picture?  What receives the `/rest/consumer/update` request?  How is the JSON string marshaled back into Java objects?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. While I was writing this question, I figuered out effekt is wrong spelled. In my question its spelled effect, but in the app its effekt. Thats not the problem. Yes there is a Controller. I have edit it in the question.

Comment: The API works. I can use that api without any problem for example with postman. As I also mentioned, if I replace policies with a emply array "[]", it works to. The problem should be descriped in the stacktrace which I dont really understand : "Can not deserialize instance of com.policyMgmt.policy.Effect out of START_OBJECT token"

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for certain why `@RequestBody` is having difficulty deserializing JSON like `{ "$type": "Effekt", "$name": "deny" }` into an instance of the `Effekt` enum, but I think you should try writing a custom `JsonDeserializer` for your enum.

Here's [another Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637427/spring-requestbody-and-enum-value) that is similar, but not identical to the issue you're facing.  Take a look at the second answer -- the one that includes a code example of a `JsonDeserializer`.

With a bit of trail-and-error, you can probably come up with something that successfully processes JSON like you're already getting into instances of `Effekt`.

The other option would be to change the JSON representation of `Effekt` in that gets sent to the server.  Perhaps if it looked like this...

```
"effekt": "deny"
```

it would work directly with `@RequestBody`.  You could try hard-coding it in the JavaScript to test.

If you want to go this route, you will probably need to implement a custom `JsonSerializer` -- the reverse of the earlier option.

Comment: Well, first of all - thank you. I tried the hard-coded-way and used "effekt" : "deny" and it worked. But I don't like the idea to use a custom JsonSerializer or JsonDeserializer, since I will have more enums in the further. There needs to be a simple solution...