# how to convert enum request in kotlin?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, enums

I am using Kotlin with spring. I want to convert request which comes from the front end. My enum class is:

```
enum class Type() {
    PARTIAL,
    FULL;

    fun equal(type:String){
        return this.equal(type.toUpperCase())
    }
}
```

My get api request is like this

```
fun updateUserInfo(user: User, @Valid @RequestBody request: RequestBody) {...}
```

My Request body is like this:

```
class RequestBody private constructor() {

    @NotNull
    lateinit var type: Type


    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 40)
    lateinit var fullName: String
}
```

My question is this frontend might using small casing like `partial,full`. I want to add modifier irrespective of anything frontend send my Type enum should always give an upper case in **updateUserInfo** function. How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring @RequestBody and Enum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637427/spring-requestbody-and-enum-value)

Comment: @sonnet thanks. but it doesnt help :-(