# Json request body to java enum with springboot controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums

I'm trying to parse json into an enum,

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637427/spring-requestbody-and-enum-value/33639825#33639825) but none of the solutions seemed to work for me.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public enum SentStatus {
    NOT_SENT("NOT_SENT"),
    MANUAL("MANUAL"),
    MARKETPLACE("MARKETPLACE");

    public String sentStatus;

    SentStatus(String sentStatus) {
        this.sentStatus = sentStatus;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return sentStatus;
    }

    public String getSentStatus() {
        return this.sentStatus;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static SentStatus fromText(String sentStatus) { //called, but sentStatus is always null
        for (SentStatus s : SentStatus.values()) {
            if (s.getSentStatus().equals(sentStatus)) {
                return s;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();  //<-- this is thrown
    }
}
```

and the controller

```
@PutMapping(path = "/{id}/mark-as-sent")
public InvoiceResponse markAsSent(
    @PathVariable UUID id, @RequestBody SentStatus sentStatus) {
    return this.invoiceService
        .markInvoiceAsSent(id, sentStatus);
}
```

But when trying to hit the endpoint with the following json body

```
{"sentStatus":"MARKETPLACE"}
```

The controller returns (with no error outputted in the console)

```
{
    "message": "Message body not in valid format"
}
```

Comment: That JSON isn't a value of a status; it's a JSON object containing a property named `sentStatus` with a value of a status. Model it accordingly.

Comment: sorry wdym 'That JSON isn't a value of a status'?

Comment: here is all info you need about serilizing and deserializing into enums https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums